# How to scale an AI assistant in regards to a changing database

Tags: database, artificial-intelligence, schema, chatbot, rasa

I know I am asking a very general question but what would be an approach to scale an AI assistant connected to a database endpoint to handle future troubleshooting problems with a changing SQL database(addition of new variables, etc.) and database schema with minimal source code refactoring?

Specifically I am using RASA, an open source conversational chatbot AI

Answer (score 0):

If changing what's in your database will let your users do new things, then a certain level of refactoring is probably going to be unavoidable.

If you just want people to be able to query a database through a conversational UI I'd recommend a very broad action that lets users select the field they want to query (possibly using buttons to avoid typos, or adding some data validation) and then provide a value for each of the selected fields. I'd probably use a form to collect all the information you want to pass to the query.

Comment: I have a few database options including one in XML. I will be able to query multiple of these sources at the same time using JQuery and provide the data points to the AI. I do think the form is viable as it is a healthcare application.

Comment: In Rasa, a form is just a way to collect multiple slots without having to provide a bunch of example stories. It's still hosted wherever your Rasa assistant is hosted.